# Java was started but returned exist code =1 error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I recently added a new project into eclipse. Eclipse already had another project in it which was working fine. But after adding this new project I am unable to open eclipse. It gives the java error=1

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check the `.log` file in the workspace `.metadata` directory for a more detailed message. There might also be a log file in the `configuration` directory in the Eclipse install directory.

Comment: I realized it was not detecting my java path. So i gave the path in the config file. it is working now. Thanks for the reply though